Fokker-Planck equation for Partial and Frational SDEs
Let a stochastic process governed by a SDE similar to:
$$dx_t = a(x_t, t) +b(x_t, t)dW_t$$
where $a$ and $b$ are deterministic functions and $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.
One can define the quantile function associated with the system ($Q(u,t)$) as:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{Q(u,t)}f(x,t) \delta x=u $$ where $f$ is the probability density function of x and t, and u is the percentile.
Using some calculus one can obtain:
$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}=a(Q, t)-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial b^2}{\partial Q}+\frac{b^2(Q, t)}{2}\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial u}\right)^{-2} \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial u^2}$$
which known as the quantilized Fokker–Planck equation (https://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahwts/lgsnotes/EJAM_Quantiles.pdf for more).
My question is: is it possible to derive something similar also for partial SDEs and for fractional SDEs?
